# Закрытие вопросов по базовым действиям для чего-либо

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, модерация, закрытие-вопросов

Заметил, что достаточно часто люди пытаются закрыть как всеобъемлющие вопросы, где спрашивается о неком примитивном действии, когда спрашивающий не знает, с чего начать.

На мой взгляд, это вопросы, в которых нужно просто подтолкнуть человека в нужном направлении, не слишком расписывая всё слишком подробно, но в то же время указав, как подобное вообще делается. Если человек явно спрашивает упрощённую версию, то можно её и дать. Такие ответы очень полезны, когда сталкиваешься с чем-то новым и даже не знаешь, с чего начать.

Вот два примера подобных вопросов:
[Сценарии/скрипты для работы в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419502/178988)
[Расширение для Visual Studio 2013: добавление кнопки в стандартное (контекстное) меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419365/178988)

Comment: Ну, почему бы не написать комментарий и проголосовать против закрытия?

Comment: @VladD, я говорю о таком типе вопросов в целом. Это уже не первые вопросы такого плана, которые пытаются закрыть, не перекапывать же мне весь сайт в поисках дополнительных примеров. На мой взгляд они полезны, причём не только для автора, но и для других людей, кому впервые понадобится сделать нечто подобное. И всеобъемлющими они тоже не являются, поскольку нужно только показать основы, а дальше человек сам разберётся.

Comment: Первый вопрос совершенно бессмысленный. Автор знает, что ему нужно "что-то типа расширения для браузера". Собственно, он адекватно представляет себе картину. Что там ещё можно поверхностно раскрыть? Направление куда нужно задать? / Второй вопрос попахивает RTFM. Собственно, RTFM — это и есть направление. Автор вон что-то там накатал в ответе самому себе, но эта информация, как мне видится, всё равно бесполезна для любого, кто не осилил документацию. / Ну не вижу я пользы ни в одном из этих вопросов, хотя про второй в принципе можно поспорить, там менее однозначно.

Comment: @Athari а я вот с Вами совершенно не согласен. Первый вопрос конкретный - ЧЕМ это реализовать и ответ на него есть конкретный - "user script", они же "пользовательские скрипты". Как и на второй вопрос - на RTFM есть конкретное направление в виде ссылки, поскольку сформулировать запрос и выйти на нужную информацию довольно сложно. Если для Вас что-то бессмысленно поскольку вы это знаете, то это не значит, что оно бессмысленно для всех, с учетом, что ответ на вопрос вполне можно дать конкретный и  обоснованный.

Comment: и вот что характерно - вопрос про расширение закрыли, а вопрос с "можно договориться о сделке" пока открыт. @AlexKrass, вы зря удалили это из вопроса IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

"Конкретность" вопроса может очень сильно зависеть от контекста.

Например, [вопрос про расширение Visual Studio 2013](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419365/) на самом деле просто плохо сформулирован. Но любому, кто пытался писать расширения - он предельно ясен.

Пункт в *главное меню* позволяет добавить *стандартный* визард. Про это нет смысла спрашивать. Подразумевается, что любой, кто пытается ответить на вопрос про расширение студии об этом знает.

А вот как переставить тот же пункт куда-то еще - вполне нормальный вопрос, который возникает у каждого второго новичка. Автор дал на него вполне конкретный и однозначный ответ, которого нет в FM - достаточно посмотреть на количество плюсов. Это тот мост через пропасть между "Hello World!" и подробной документацией с пачкой гуидов от Microsoft®, в поисках которого многие и приходят на SO (или лезут в гугл, который приводит их на SO).

И в то же самое время для тех, кто никогда не пытался писать расширение для студии - вопрос кажется очередным "скажите что почитать". close as too broad!

Проблема не во всеобъемлющности вопроса. Скорее, он просто кажется всеобъемлющим из-за не слишком удачной формулировки. Это можно решить редактированием, возможно даже просто сменой заголовка. Например, привести код из стандартного визарда, и спросить как переставить пункт в другое меню.

То же самое касается и предыдущего вопроса того же автора - [Как создать расширение для Visual Studio 2013](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419123/). Он кажется общим, но на самом деле на него можно дать вполне конкретный и которткий ответ. Который будет вполне востребован, с учетом происходящей смены механизма расширений в VS 2015. И который я не стал писать, посчитав что вопрос удалят. Это же расширения к студии, а не выбор плагина для валидации к JQuery или книги по HTML - тут нет никакого разнообразия и сотен различных вариантов ответов.

---

А вот вопрос про скрипты - на самом деле плохо прикрытое предложение о фрилансе. Этого не видно после редактирования, но вполне очевидно что автор не искал подсказки или помощи в выборе направления. Вот зачем он пришел на SO:

> Либо, как лучший вариант, можно договориться о сделке, пишите.

Такое надо удалять не задумываясь ни на минуту. Автора не к чему подталкивать, он этого не хочет. Ему нужен фрилансер, котому он соизволит объяснить детали. Он не будет редактировать вопрос. Он даже не вернется на сайт, чтобы прочитать ответ. Потому что ему быстрее ответят [на объявление на каком-нибудь fl.ru](https://www.fl.ru/projects/2286894/nujno-napisat-nebolshoy-skript_makros_stsenariy-dlya-brauzera.html).

Answer (score 4):

Все вопросы без конкретной проблемы должны закрываться/удаляться. На это есть несколько причин. Самая главная - в Stack Overflow изначально была заложена идея коллективной помощи в узкоспециализированном вопросе по программированию. Невозможно дать однозначно верный ответ на вопрос, который не содержит конкретного вопроса. Stack Overflow - это не просто место для получения ответов, это база знаний, коллекция многократно используемых прикладных решений. Вопрос "ни о чем" нельзя отнести к какой-либо проблеме, как результат нельзя и повторно использовать, то есть такие знания не несут пользы сообществу.

**Обновление**

Вопросы на вроде "Как изучить Java за 3 дня?" хоть и интересны многим начинающим специалистам, но они бесполезны для сообщества.

Если говорить, о случаях, когда надо поверхностно понять как делать что-то, то решением, опять же, будет четко поставленный вопрос, на который, уверен, будет дан развернутый ответ. Например, представим, что я что-то слышал о расширениях для интернет-обозревателя Google Chrome, но хочу узнать подробнее. В этом случае мне хотелось бы увидеть следующее.

1. Описание самой технологии, для чего нужна, где применяется, какие возможности имеет.
2. Набор примеров кода для каждого варианта применения.

Как мне кажется, вся информация для пункта **1)** может и должна быть представлена в описание метки (в нашем случае [chrome-extension](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-extension)). Такое описание, в купе со ссылками на официальную документацию, должно отвечать на все "базовые" вопросы о технологии. Пункт **2)** это сугубо прикладные вопросы, которым всегда рады в сообществе. (Например, как реализовать взаимодействие открытой страницы сайта с расширением.)

Хочу подчеркнуть, что на Stack Overflow на русском приветствуются вопросы любой сложности: от начального уровня до экспертного. Самое главное, чтобы в вопросе было явно показано, в чем проблема.

Comment: <результат нельзя и повторно использовать ... знания не несут пользы сообществу.>
Напротив. Есть куча людей, которые впервые захотели сделать расширение. Они ещё не знают, как его сделать и хотят разобраться. Для этого очень полезным оказывается простой пример, где автор не лезет в глубь, а просто рассказывает, какие вообще шаги надо выполнить, чтобы получилось хоть что-то. Неужели сам никогда не искал по принципу "мне надо вот это, а что для этого использовать и как я не знаю"? Обрати внимание, что я сказал "искал", а не "спрашивал".

Comment: @Qwertiy Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все проще.

"Люди" пытаются закрыть вопрос только потому что **не знают, что на него ответить**. Логика при этом примерно такая: "если я, такой умный и красивый, не знаю, что ответить на вопрос, то вопрос не имеет смысла!"

А дальше уже встает вопрос об уровне этих самых закрывателей. Который ожидаемо плачевен. И в итоге мы имеем стадо бандерлогов, *затаптывающих* Маугли, посмевшего спросить про то, чего они не знают и никогда сами не пробовали.

Пример: [Оцените класс для работы с MySql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419862/%D0%9E%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-mysql)
- прекрасный вопрос, полный хрестоматийных ошибок, подробный разбор которых весьма пригодится пытливым умам, которые не хотят говнокодить по раз и навсегда заведенному шаблону вместе с остальными 85%

Но каким-то вахтерам он показался неправильным. И единственный ответ, который они знают - линейкой по рукам, "не выпендривайся, будь как мы все".

И ладно бы трафик был как на родительском. Я бы понял столь активное закрытие. Но вопросов-то и так с гулькин нос, чтобы еще и синдром вахтера на них тренировать

Comment: Поверьте, с уровнем знаний закрывающих все в порядке, и никакого заговора тут нет. Просто есть правила, которые нужно соблюдать, и которые мало кто читает. Опросники и вопросы по сбору мнений - неформат для StackOverflow.

Comment: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  [Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Если есть вопросы касающиеся правил, можно обсудить их на Мете или [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Но переходить на личности ("бандерлоги", "вахтеры") - не комильфо.

Comment: Я еще не видел ни одного закрытого вопроса, который можно было бы отнести к вашему описанию. Указанный вами пример: 1) опросник, 2) содержал код на внешнем ресурсе. Как результат, был закрыт.