# Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, новые-участники, раньше-было-лучше

За несколько месяцев, проведенные здесь, я вижу явный разрыв целей активных участников\администрации и собственно наполнения ресурса.

Цели администрации (как я ее понимаю) - создать ресурс с быстрым поиском верного решения появившейся нестандартной проблемы, либо квалифицированной помощью в случае отсутствия готового решения и последующего его переиспользования. Некоторая база знаний по нестандартным ситуациям для квалифицированных специалистов в своей области, которые делятся друг с другом неочевидными моментами в процессе разработки и не должны тратить много времени на решение этих проблем.

Не могу говорить за все разделы, я их не читаю, но вот по android-разработке, к которой я имею интерес и сопутствующим темам ( Java Gradle IDE и тд.) ситуация весьма печальная.

Ни по первой ни по второй цели не наблюдается каких-то видимых продвижений.
По факту мы имеем 99% какого-то детского сада, вопросы задаются новичками, практически элементарные, решение которых лежит на поверхности при проявлении минимального усердия и хоть малейшего обучения делу, проявить себя в котором эти новички пытаются, однако не желая при этом хоть как-то научиться тому, что собрались делать.
Нет, конечно это уже обсуждалось, кому-то сложным кажется одно, кому-то другое ... Но! , к примеру из недавнего - для чего оператор `new` ... согласитесь , это где-то за гранью. Можно отвечать конечно, и я ответил, по возможности полно, в робкой надеже, что может человек попробует - у него получится и будет больше самостоятельно обучаться.

Проблема все же мне видится не совсем в этом. Проблема в том, что ресурс неуклонно превращается в начальную школу для лентяев, которые не хотят что-то узнать самостоятельно, самые основы разработки - пусть мне дядьки персонально для меня разжуют, чего я буду время за книжками проводить.

Ну и вот, такие **вопросы и ответы имеют практически нулевую ценность для специалиста**, найти именно на русском оверфлоу решение реальной трудной проблемы почти всегда невозможно.

Можно утешиться тем, что новичкам тоже нужны ответы и они их найдут здесь, НО! и тут проблема. Новички эти патологически **не хотят читать, а тем более искать**, он заходит - сразу пишет, чего ему не понятно, не пытаясь посмотреть, что возможно ответ уже есть и ждет его. Конечно, ведь его вопрос такой уникальный и важный, некогда искать решение, надо быстрее спрашивать и пусть специально для меня, в сотый раз, разжуют одно и то же, то , что написано в любом мало-мальски годном учебнике... Да, пометить, как копия, это все понятно.

Я говорю о общей тенденции, что ни одна из целей этого ресурса не достигается и это печально.

Действительные специалисты, как правило не испытывают языковой барьер и находят решение на более серьезных ресурсах, как английский оверфлоу.
Новички не хотят использовать этот ресурс, неуклонно превращающийся в справочник начинающего лентяя-разработчика, как собственно справочник, а скорее, как персональный бесплатный консультационный пункт не читавшего ничего очередного "творца" шедевра.

Все это усугубляется тем, что я , например, не вижу какого-то разумного решения сложившейся ситуации.
Потеря интереса специалистов связана, по моему мнению с тем, что в один прекрасный момент становится просто не интересно цитировать того же Эккеля, а читать "вопросы" иной раз без нервных судорог невозможно, приходиться принимать меры для того, чтобы успокоится, а кому это надо? сознательно портить себе настроение, чтобы потом его восстанавливать.
С другой стороны найти решение действительно сложной проблемы здесь часто невозможно, проще и быстрее обратиться на английский оверфлоу.

Comment: Минусуйте такие вопросы, жмите "закрытие", минусуйте тех, кто отвечает на такие вопросы.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/239/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy я говорю совсем о другой проблеме

Comment: Ничего нового тут нет, все давно известно, низкая педагогическая ценность, рак на нулевой, все плохо, зачем это надо если есть оригинальный мануал, выхода нет, мне настолько все равно что я не могу больше молчать и.т.д.и.т.п. Контраргументы просты как 3 рубля: 1) Вас вообще никто не заставляет сюда заходить, что-то писать, кому-то помогать и читать вопросы с нулевой. 2) Больно? Зато бесплатно.

Comment: Проблема другая, но не совсем. Написал ответом, а то объёмно получилось.

Comment: @igumnov очевидно, что игнорирование проблемы никак не решит проблему и не поможет стать ресурсу тем, чем он задумывался.

Comment: @Nofate закрытие и минусование "простых" вопросов тоже не решит озвученной мной проблемы.

Comment: @pavlofff Это верно если проблема не надуманная.

Comment: Вопрос, возможно, решит минусование _ответов_ на вопросы, на которые не следует отвечать. С другой стороны, если вопрос освещён в любой книге, то на него скорее всего уже дан ответ, и надо закрыть как дубликат. А если вопрос не несёт познавательной ценности (как мне найти максимум массива?) — ну так закрывать как неинтересный сообществу.

Comment: Я человек в программировании относительно новый. Разделы по android не посещал - т.к. занимаюсь веб разработкой. Но, мне есть что вам возразить: 1. Само по себе формулирование даже простейших вопросов в виде текста - это уже отличное обучение для новичка (а цель ресурса - обучить).  2. Я пришел сюда буквально только что - и вижу у себя прогресс. Значит ресурс работает хорошо. 3. Чем больше вы знаете, тем большее количество тривиальных вопросов для вас возникает. И тем меньше интересных для вас вопросов. Только и всего.

Comment: Тема с "заминусовыванием" довольно неоднозначна. Не каждый может правильно трактовать "сухой" текст книги о программировании, а таких книг, поверьте, довольно много. В итоге это вытекает в полнейшее непонимание базовых вещей, которое ни к чему хорошему не приводит. В данной ситуации объяснение "простыми словами" от практикующих людей гораздо эффективнее. И тут вопрос даже не в лени, а в том, что обучение тоже должно быть относительно простым, понятным и приятным, дабы привлекать "молодняк".

Comment: Вот да, у меня тоже иногда (фейспалм происходит) происходит удивление, какие новички "нудные" когда я помогаю новичкам... в общем, бегло прочитал 7 параграф и поставил плюс :)

Comment: На правах идеи. Хорошим вариантом было бы выделить некую "песочницу", где можно было бы задавать вопросы, если считаешь себя новичком или свой вопрос простым. Это можно сделать в виде отдельных тегов или даже сообщества. Вопрос в оптимальности и затратах. Варианты со своими плюсами и минусами. Думаю, что озвученные проблемы так можно решить.

Answer (score 29):

Утверждение, что SO существует только для нестандартных проблем с неочевидными моментами — неверно. ["Joel says that the only bad simple question is a duplicate simple question"](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) (Joel в этой цитате — это глава компании, которая управляет SO).

На «очевидные» вопросы с разных углов можно ответить — разным людям разные ответы больше могут подходить. Многие «стандартные» проблемы имеют неочевидные моменты — всё зависит насколько глубоко вы готовы копать — SO позволяет привести детальный ответ даже на самый простой вопрос. Никакая книга/документация не может позволить себе такой фокус. Справедливости ради, даже [опытные участники SO могут этого не понимать](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286640/do-we-need-a-canonical-question-about-c-initialization/286647#comment158344_286647).

Ваш вопрос написан с точки зрения полезности для человека, отвечающего на вопросы на SO, но основная полезность SO — в предоставлении ответов для посетителей из поисковиков, которых на порядок больше чем других участников (вот таблица за 2010: [How do Stack Overflow users find the site?](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/)).

Очевидно, что большинство вопросов (и даже большинство [уместных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [хороших](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) вопросов) и [самые популярные вопросы на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) являются простыми (с точки зрения текущего обсуждения, нет существенной разницы между большим SO и SO на русском).

Это затрудняет поиск вопросов для людей, которые любят *отвечать* только на «интересные» вопросы. И (в меньшей степени) это может помешать найти нужную ссылку в поисковике для людей, *имеющих* интересный вопрос.

Легко ответить на вопрос «что делать если вы видите простой вопрос, который повторно задан 10 раз»:

Не нужно 10 раз в 10 разных местах Эккеля цитировать, чтобы ответить на один и тот же вопрос: используйте «золотой молот» — если вы опытный участник (в метке), одного вашего голоса достаточно, чтобы закрыть вопрос как дубликат, в противном случае просто проголосуйте за закрытие или оставьте комментарий со ссылкой на вопрос-дубликат.

Проблема некачественных вопросов — это проблема [«вечного сентября»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8C). [Медиана репутации на SO равна  **единице**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296969/4279). Это не значит, что опытных участников нет, просто абсолютных новичков гораздо больше. Не существует общего решения проблемы сигнал/шум для содержимого, генерируемого пользователями на популярных сайтах.

Отслеживая вопросы только в избранных метках (наборе меток), можно изолировать себя от многих нежелательных вопросов.

Многочисленные элементы сайта (голосование, комментарии, справка с такими разделами как [«Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), кнопки
 «править», «закрыть», «тревога», различные [очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review)) помогают повысить качество сайта.

Готовы ли вы делиться своим временем и знанием в этом несовершенном мире — это ваше личное дело.

Comment: Большинство вопросов на SO, это просьбы помочь им решить ихнюю проблему, которые выкладываются неграмотно на сайте, приводят читающих в конфуз и не отвечают требованиям/пожеланиям сайта писать хорошие вопросы. По этой причине это большинство вопросов надо закрывать и удалять. Те которые получают готовое решение на сайте, редко вносят свой вклад путём голосования, поскольку им это не надо. Поэтому сайт превращается из Q/A в форум.

Comment: @RomanC не имеет значения **кто** и **почему** задал вопрос, если ответ может помочь многим другим людям. Если ответ на вопрос может помочь, попробуйте его улучшить, если нет голосуйте за закрытие.

Answer (score 22):

**Простые вопросы**. На первый взгляд, проблема разрыва квалификации аудитории Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском преувеличена. В обоих сообществах задаются как сложные так и простые вопросы и, скорее всего, в одинаковой пропорции. Как подтверждение гипотезы, можно видеть, что практически по каждой функции JQuery на Stack Overflow есть вопрос о том, как её использовать, хотя существует официальная документация с описанием и примерами использования. Вряд ли такие вопросы можно отнести к сложным.

Самое интересно, насколько полезны подобные простые вопросы? Можно предположить, что очень даже! Попробую провести аналогию. Как производить умножение, вычитание и т. д. над целыми числами учит практически каждый человек на Земле, а вот про [Гильбертово пространство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) знает далеко не каждый. Ко всему, научиться умножать намного проще. Вопрос: будут ли знания о том, как производить простейшие арифметические операции бесполезны?

На мой взгляд, пользу следует считать не по тому, на сколько сложен вопрос, а по тому, сколько человеко-часов труда реальных людей удалось сэкономить за счет публикации вопроса с ответом на Stack Overflow на русском. В этой проекции, скорее всего, чем проще вопрос, тем большему количеству разработчиков он может быть интересен. Как результат, не стоит так уж сильно ругать слишком простые вопросы.

**Лентяи**. Простой вопрос - это не признак лености. Простой вопрос - это признак новичка. Для опытного специалиста характерны два важных качества:

- широкое знание предметной области;
- хорошая осведомленность о качественных источниках пополнения знаний.

Поэтому при возникновении какой-либо задачи опытный специалист (например, системный администратор):

- в точности вспоминает, какую команду и как надо выполнить, поскольку он уже неоднократно ее исполнял;
- в общих чертах вспоминает, какие команды могут подойти, и обращается к руководству пользователя, чтобы прояснить детали;
- заходит на любимый сетевой ресурс, где можно найти подходящие руководства;
- обращается к поиску, чтобы найти необходимый сетевой ресурс.

Новичок же ещё не знает ни предметной области, ни источников информации. В дополнение, сам поиск информации является навыком, который вырабатывается со временем. Также интересно то, что задать вопрос намного сложнее, чем искать ответ через поисковик! Так для того чтобы задать вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском, нужно:

1. зарегистрироваться;
2. осмыслить проблему;
3. сформулировать ее в терминах предметной области;
4. записать вопрос.

Для того чтобы найти ответ в поисковой системе, нужно:

1. отправить запрос по ключевым словам;
2. просмотреть выдачу поисковой машины.

Если человек разбирается в предметной области, то найти ответ через поиск гораздо быстрее и проще, чем спросить на форуме и ждать ответа. Ежели человек только начал разбираться в предметной области, то всё наоборот. В таком случае начинающий специалист просто не знает, что и как искать.

**Обучение в формате проблема-решение**. Обучение по книгам требует намного большего времени, нежели использование примеров кода. Например, столкнувшись с задачей, требующей новых знаний, мы не спешим идти покупать десяток книг или читать всю документацию. Вместо этого, мы ищем пример использования нужной библиотеки. Такое обучение крайне важно как для новичков, так и для состоявшихся специалистов. Например, будучи специалистом С++, вряд ли мы будем знать все возможные способы работы с массивами в Python. В этом случае вопросы вида "Как отсортировать массив в Python" для нас будут крайне полезны, ведь они позволят нам сэкономить уйму времени!

На мой взгляд, задавая вопросы, начинающие программисты вносят огромный вклад в развитие базы знаний русскоязычного сообщества. Своими вопросами они говорят знатокам, в каких именно знаниях нуждаются программисты, приступающие к изучению той или иной технологии.

#### Как повысить сложность задаваемых вопросов?

**Задавать вопросы нам самим!**

Изначально, Stack Overflow на русском (тогда еще ХэшКод) был запущен двумя товарищами исключительно для того, чтобы перенести нашу базу знаний из текстового файла, хранящегося на диске в Интернет, для более удобного взаимодействия. Эта база знаний была создана в процессе изучения новых технологий. Мы вели конспекты - ставили перед собой задачу (вопрос), а находя решение (ответ) добавляли его в файлик.

Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество русскоязычных программистов. Именно мы сами ответственны за размер и качество нашей базы прикладных знаний. Вряд ли наши англоязычные коллеги создадут её за нас.

**Если мы видим, что имеет место быть недостаток сложных вопросов, давайте задавать их!**

Поиск решения (новых знаний) - это крайне полезный навык, который развивается до совершенства к тому моменту, когда мы становимся профессионалами своего дела. Как результат, вопрос от знатока - скорее исключение, чем правило. Если мы хотим иметь большое количество сложных вопросов, то нам стоит самостоятельно задавать их! Так сталкиваясь с новой задачей, перед поиском информации в интернете, просто задайте вопрос. Вы сможете опубликовать ответ позже, когда найдете на него ответ.

Уверен, таким образом, мы сможем создать свободно распространяемую базу знаний не только для начинающих, но и для мастеров своего дела!

Comment: Вы пишете `сталкиваясь с новой задачей, перед поиском информации в интернете, просто задайте вопрос`, следовательно в таком случае получается, что вот запросто нельзя минусовать-удалять "глупые для специалиста" вопросы, поскольку задавая свой первый в новой области вопрос человек, естественно не знает, окажется ли он нормальным или дурацким (и соответственно польют его помоями или наградят). Вот лично я сейчас поостерегся бы спросить тут хоть что-нибудь.

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском создан с целью кристаллизации знания, а не оценки профессиональных способностей участников. То есть идея не в том, "дурацкий" ли вопрос кто-либо задает, а в том прикладной ли он. "Дурацких" прикладных вопросов практически не бывает. Баллы репутации отражают: 1) вклад участника, 2) на сколько сообщество ему доверяет. Если говорить про оценку вопросов, то оценка показывает на сколько данный вопрос полезен, хорошо оформлен и т. д. Идеально, удаляться/получать голос против должны не тематические и не соответствующие формату вопросы.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что сейчас новичек без последствий может задать вопрос `"как в Linux раскрывать file.tar.xz"` перед поиском в гугле? (и ему даже ответят -- http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441)

Comment: @avp Мне кажется это вполне разумным. Особенно, если автор хочет ответить на свой вопрос самостоятельно.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это было бы разумно, даже если бы он *не успел* ответить самостоятельно. Николай, попытайтесь донести эту мысль до основной массы отвечающих.

Answer (score 11):

## О специалистах и простых вопросах

Я полностью уверен, что специалисты тоже читают простые вопросы, когда-то заданные новичками.

Никто из нас не является специалистом во всех областях. И когда мы осваиваем что-то новое или просто решаем задачу в малознакомой нам области, нам пригождаются именно эти простые вопросы вроде "как сложить два числа на brainfuck".

Другое дело, что те, кто стал специалистом хотя бы в одной области, реже задают простые вопросы, и вот почему:

1. Они могут правильно сформулировать проблему.
2. Они могут правильно сформулировать поисковой запрос и выделить релевантные результаты.
3. Если они нашли частично подходящее решение, то они могут адаптировать его для своей задачи.
4. Часто им достаточно только намёка на путь решения задачи.

В наше время технологии развиваются очень быстро, и так же быстро устаревают прежние знания. Специалист теперь - это уже не просто тот, кто имеет много знаний и навыков, а скорее тот, кто развил навык быстро приобретать знания и навыки. Потому он и не задаёт много простых вопросов, что быстро учится на чужих ошибках.

## Спасти простой вопрос хорошим ответом

Простой вопрос часто бывает направлен на какую-то очень базовую концепцию и обнаруживает непонимание автором этой концепции. На этот вопрос можно дать хороший развёрнутый ответ, который раскрывает смысл и даёт фундаментальное понимание. Это понимание, в свою очередь, сэкономит много человеко-часов, багов и вопросов-дублей на ту же тему.

Например:

- [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/197067/181472)
- [Является ли переменная объектом в ООП?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8337/181472)
- [Обязательно ли использовать else?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432713/181472) (этот только с виду простой).

Answer (score 3):

А счего вы решили что в глазах посетителей сервис Q&A это база знаний? Вы можете о себе думать что хотите, но если вы выглядете как Q&A, двигаетесь как Q&A и крякаете как Q&A вы будете Q&A!

То что посетитель не может найти существующий ответ это не его проблема, а проблема некачетсвенного поиска. Хотя да, стоит признать, немало тех кому любой поиск побоку.

Спецам больше нужен не Q&A, а место где можно проблемы обсудить, поспорить и, главное, обменяться знаниями.

Comment: *Спецам больше нужен не Q&A, а место где можно проблемы обсудить, поспорить и, главное, обменяться знаниями.* Прекрасно, в интернете масса таких мест. А у нас - Q&A база знаний.

Comment: @Nofate SO это лучший Q&A на сегодня, и поэтому я здесь. Однако Q&A нельзя считать базой знаний даже в случае SO. Почему? Очень просто, знание это понимание принципов. Большой список пар вопрос/ответ, структурированный с помощью тегов, коим является SO, к знанию, т.е. к пониманию принципов, приближает очень медленно.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё из той же области:
[Закрытие вопросов по базовым действиям для чего-либо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/239/178988)
[А что если разрешить?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/623/178988)

Общее между этими тремя темами в том, что закрываются вопросы, которые были бы интересны и могли бы привлечь людей.

На вопрос "как найти максимум в массиве" ответит кто угодно, этот ответ почти бесполезен, а спрашивающий такое вряд ли способен сам ответить на какой-то вопрос.

Вопрос "как мне впервые написать расширение для браузера" полезен тем, кто в принципе в программировании разбирается, но конкретно этого ни разу не делал. Эти люди вполне могут обладать значительным опытом в других областях.

Вопросы "какой язык выбрать" и "что прочитать" показывают заинтересованность в обучении. Возможно, когда человек выучится, он станет задавать интересные вопросы здесь же и отвечать на вопросы других людей.

Но всё это считается нетематическим и закрывается.

Comment: А что мешает заинтересованным лицам поискать и прочесть книгу, документацию или руководство (tutorial) по данной теме? Пусть даже краткое. Если человек не в состоянии набрать в Google (или в другой поисковой системе) запрос _как написать расширение для браузера_ и посетить сайты хотя бы с первой страницы результатов поиска, то либо ему лень и не так уж он и заинтересован, либо он привык, что за него всё делают, либо это уже диагноз. Я понимаю, если человек что-то прочитал и не понял какие-то конкретные моменты, но столь общие вопросы ни о чем хорошем не говорят.

Comment: @Regent, так почему бы ему не дать эту ссылку в ответе? Гугл много чего найдёт, в том числе, отвратного качества. Что плохого спросить, ожидая увидеть ссылку на качественный материал от тех, кто в теме разбирается? А то в варианте скопипастил код, вместо круглых скобок угловые мы говорим "добро пожаловать, вот исправление", а в варианте что требуется, чтобы сделать что-то - "катись отсюда, это оффтопик". Должно-то быть наоборот...

Comment: То, что я исправляю чужой JS-код или вообще пишу его за автора почти с нуля, если ответ укладывается в пару абстрактных абзацев, - да, есть за мной такой "грешок". По поводу ссылок на качественный материал. Во-первых, ссылки могут жить меньше, чем SO, и для будущих посетителей будут бесполезны. Во-вторых, "качественный материал" - понятие субъективное. А при слишком широком вопросе материалы, предложенные разными пользователями, вообще могут радикально отличаться. Получается эдакая выбора из Гугла, проведённая за пользователя.

Comment: В конце концов, почему ответы из одной ссылки плохи, уже много раз обсуждалось на http://meta.stackexchange.com. Если же вы готовы развёрнутый ответ и использовать ссылку лишь в качестве подкрепления аргументов или доп. информации - по крайней мере, ответ нельзя будет считать плохим. Однако проблема всеобъемлемости вопроса и, как следствие, субъективных ответов-советов остаётся.

Comment: Можно ещё вспомнить про то, что со временем то, что было качественным, становится устаревшим (некачественным). И про то, что лучше дать человеку удочку, чем рыбу.

Comment: @Regent, так я как раз про удочку и говорю. Набор ссылок, как сделать - это и есть удочка. А код поиска максимума в массиве - это как раз рыба. Да, с недостатками ссылок всё понятно. Но есть сайты, которые вряд ли закроются в ближайшее время. Кстати, википедия эту проблему ведь архивированием источников решает?

Answer (score 2):

Знаю, что запоздал с ответом, но хочу высказаться.

1. Да, простых вопросов больше, чем сложных.
2. Вопросы "сделайте дз" нужно закрывать (Чистим базу знаний от мусора).
3. Сложные вопросы тоже есть.
4. 99% простых вопросов - явно преувеличение. А даже если это так, то как минимум 1-2 "сложных" вопросов в день есть, ведь кол-во вопросов у нас 120 шт/день.
5. На старые вопросы тоже можно отвечать. При чём как и вопросы недельной давности, так и на вопросы, заданные много лет назад. Среди старых вопросов точно есть куча неотвеченных сложных. Ответы на такие вопросы = пополнение базы знаний.
6. Если вы хотите найти "сложные вопросы" (сложные по вашим меркам), можно использовать метки. Как связаны метки и сложность вопросов? Мне кажется, что если отфильтровать вопросы по меткам [ваш-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%88-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) [какой-нибудь-фреймворк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba), то вопросы будут ну хотя бы чуточку поинтереснее, чем например "Почему не работает оператор if?".