# Примеры хорошо заданных «недетских» вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Можно встретить [мнение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/23044):

> Ну и вот, такие вопросы и ответы имеют практически нулевую ценность для специалиста, **найти именно на русском оверфлоу решение реальной трудной проблемы почти всегда невозможно**<sup>выделение моё</sup>

Хочу понять насколько подобные "трудные проблемы" распространены в повседневной работе программиста (фраза "практически нулевую ценность для специалиста" подразумевает, что: ~0% вопросов, встретившихся за день в реальной работе являются лёгкими, их решение можно найти на Stack Overflow, и соответственно ~100% — нельзя [что может не соответствовать действительности]). Примеры должны легко в голову приходить.

Фраза "хорошо заданный" [вопрос] понимается здесь как в [/help/how-to-answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Плохие вопросы:

- непонятны или не содержат конкретных подробностей, что не позволяет однозначно определить проблему;
- провоцируют обмен мнениями, а не фактами;
- требуют слишком много наводящей информации для полного ответа;
- требуют ответов на несколько вопросов сразу;
- не относятся к тематике Stack Overflow на русском, согласно определению в [/help/on-topic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

В голове мнение засело [где-то после пары лет работы программистом (давно)], что любую проблему можно разбить на [возможно длинную] череду (лес) простых шагов — Stack Overflow вопросов (то есть путешествие может быть и в 1000 миль, но каждый отдельный шаг выполним и не требует сверхъестественных способностей — уровней абстракции может быть много, но каждый отдельный вопрос в основном в терминах одного уровня можно решить (подглядывая на другие уровни). К примеру, браузер может из миллионов строк кода состоять и потребовать миллионов отдельных вопросов, которые можно на SO задать). *Нужны контр-примеры* (примеры неразбиваемых, несводимых к перевариваемым кускам, вопросов). Думаю, дюжины разнородных примеров может быть достаточно, чтобы последующие примеры уже самостоятельно получить.

Интересуют реальные вопросы из практики, на которые есть ответ где-то (идеально со ссылкой). Здесь возможен лёгкий ответ — могу очевидного не видеть.

---

Уточнение на основе замечаний из существующих [ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7279/23044):

> Обращаю внимание, что там написано "для специалиста", а не "для разработчика". Т. е. подразумевается, что человек уже опытный и встретившиеся ему простые вопросы вполне способен решить сам.

Не надо путать: *могу* решить задачу и *имеет смысл* самостоятельно тратить время на решение задачи. Настоящий специалист не изобретает велосипедов, не имея хорошей на то причины. Настоящий специалист видит дальше в том числе потому что [стоит на плечах гигантов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) и не тратит время на решение задач, для которых уже хорошие решения существуют, без особых на то оснований.

Stack Overflow для того и существует, чтобы не нужно было с нуля каждому типичные задачи решать.

---

> Это так же снижает вероятность попадания именно на русскоязычный сайт с текстовым описанием требований.

Я понимаю, что цитата в начале данного вопроса именно о ru.SO говорит. Но с точки зрения желаемых примеров, разницы между [en]SO и ru.SO нет. Интересуют примеры  «недетских» вопросов на любом языке.

Comment: По моему тут у нас проблемка образовывается - любой приведённый тут пример с большой долей вероятности попадёт на сайт, и будет тут же исключен, как неподходящий..

Comment: @vp_arth меня дух, а не буква обсуждения интересует. То есть или у меня просто ментальный блок (я не вижу очевидных другим примеров) или всё-таки подавляющее большинство практических проблем можно свести к череде SO вопросов.

Comment: Ок, примеры задач: "реализовать сервер печати штрихкодов, поддерживающий принтеры Zebra", "произвести интеграцию гемоанализатора AU-480 с ЛИС"... В общем, весь класс задач, когда нужно брать в руки спецификацию и делать.

Comment: @VladD, Похоже я вообще не понял о чём вопрос, пошёл перечитывать. Мне кажется, что нужны примеры вопросов, которых нет в SO.

Comment: @vp_arth: Ну или я неправильно понял :-D

Comment: @jfs: Свести к череде простых вопросов, наверное, можно в большинстве случаев. Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы правильно построить промежуточный вопрос, [нужно знать большую часть ответа](https://unhandled-exception.ru/others/books/verniy-vopros/).

Comment: @VladD: конечно: правильный вопрос — может быть половиной решения. Спрашивающий может не знать насколько прост/сложен ответ. Может быть невинный вопрос, ответом на который года исследований могут понадобиться (к примеру, в XIX веке спросить: "почему небо голубое?").

Answer (score 6):

Для меня классическим примером нередуцируемого, полезного, но отличного и очень нужного вопроса, является такой:

> Объясните, как работает async/await (в предположении, что потоки, пул потоков и т. п. объяснять не нужно).

Этот вопрос немного грешит по 3-му пункту («требуют слишком много наводящей информации для полного ответа»), но тем не менее очень важен.

Ещё хорошие, сложные вопросы из личной практики:

- [в чём польза генераторов по сравнению с возвратом материализованных коллекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505018/10105)
- [почему `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/10105) и [его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/191857/10105) [вариации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/10105).
- [как вернуть значение из асинхронного колбэка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/10105) и многочисленные дубликаты
- почему приложение подвисает при вызове синхронной длинной функции в UI-потоке? (100500 дубликатов)

Comment: Детали от языка зависят, но на вопрос "как устроен async/await" можно содержательно ответить (хотя вопрос близок к границе "слишком обширный" для SO) В целом это хороший пример. Некоторым людям незнакомым с этим понятием может быть тяжело сперва его уловить—ничего сложного но требует привычки, опыта/знакомства с рядом задач. На монады в этом смысле похоже: куча вводных руководств, но пока не озарит, толку мало¶ Вот человек за 45 минут с нуля async/await реализует (на Питоне) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4 (для тех кому легче на примере конкретного кода знакомиться с понятиями)

Answer (score 2):

> фраза "практически нулевую ценность для специалиста" подразумевает, что: ~0% вопросов, встретившихся за день в реальной работе являются лёгкими, их решение можно найти на Stack Overflow, и соответственно ~100% — нельзя

Неправильно понимаешь. Обращаю внимание, что там написано *"для специалиста",* а не *"для разработчика".* Т. е. подразумевается, что человек уже опытный и встретившиеся ему простые вопросы вполне способен решить сам.

Например, я не полезу искать, [что мне делать с NullReferenceException](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/178988), ещё менее интересны мне сотни вопросов, вызванных той же проблемой. И я сам знаю [как отсортировать массив](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432369/178988). Это хорошие, очень полезные вопросы, но они нужны новичкам, а не специалистам. Вполне вероятно, что они нужны гораздо большему числу людей, чем какие-то специфические сложные вопросы, но вероятность, что специалист их ещё не знает и полезет их искать крайне мала.

Дальше, что касается поиска ответов на простые вопросы. Да, их тоже можно искать. И да, я часто ищу что-то элементарное по языкам, которые я не знаю. Например, я искал, как извлечь квадратный корень на питоне. Но даже тут есть нюанс. Вот мне совершенно лень писать гуглу `как извлечь квадратный корень на python`, вместо этого я (уже имея некие представления) напишу всего два слова `python sqrt`. Попаду ли я по такому запросу на русский сайт? Ну возможно, но вроде английский более вероятен. Аналогично я могу искать `java printf` и что угодно, вводя желаемые слова из других языков программирования с целью найти аналогичную функциональность. Это так же снижает вероятность попадания именно на русскоязычный сайт с текстовым описанием требований.

> В голове мнение засело, что любую проблему можно разбить на [возможно длинную] череду (лес) простых шагов

Вот пример вопроса и попыток его разбить:

- [Горизонтальные CSS колонки с заголовками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548594/178988)
- [Горизонтальные колонки с многоколоночными заголовками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549065/178988)
- [Обеспечить правильную ширину inline-block'у с колонками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548849/178988)

Примерно пара человекомесяцев на решение, итог, что только на css сделать нельзя, куча написанного кода и разных вариантов. Как предлагаешь разбить на более мелкие вопросы?

Comment: не существует  "специалиста", который знает всё что написано в Stack Overflow ответах.

Comment: @jfs, не существует никого, кому в реальных задачах понадобится всё, что написано на SO в ответах. Идея в том, что специалист, являясь специалистом в какой-то конкретной области, где-то около неё и работает и в реальных задачах будет сталкиваться преимущественно с задачами из этой области или около неё.

Comment: 1- вы пытаетесь сказать что "специалист" не читает Stack Overflow? (то есть все те миллионы разработчиков, которые   сайт посещают не являются "специалистами"). 2- факт: я не помню всего того что в *моих собственных ответах написано*

Comment: 1. Нет, я такого не говорил. Читать != использовать в реальных задачах. Читать != искать решение, читать можно и впрок. Речь именно о поиске, причём поиске того, с чем ты реально столкнулся в той области, с которой ты обычно работаешь. 2. Поиск написанного собой - это немного другой момент. Но да, я могу искать свой код, чтобы не думать ещё раз, как его написать. Вот только что DOMParser искал. Правда, [искал на мете](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+*parser*)...

Comment: то есть вы хотите сказать что миллионы разработчиков исключительно "впрок" читают SO? Что "реальные" задачи только с нуля каждый разработчик решает или исключительно на других ресурсах решения находит?

Comment: @jfs, ты как-то совсем не так интерпретируешь мои слова.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу понять насколько подобные "трудные проблемы" распространены в
>   повседневной работе программиста (фраза "практически нулевую ценность
>   для специалиста" подразумевает, что: ~0% вопросов, встретившихся за
>   день в реальной работе являются лёгкими, их решение можно найти на
>   Stack Overflow, и соответственно ~100% — нельзя [что может не
>   соответствовать действительности]). Примеры должны легко в голову
>   приходить.

Вообще, нет. Эта фраза то и значит, что "имеет практически нулевую ценность для специалиста". Я не знаю, как вы из этой фразы сделали выводы про 0% и 100%.

> К примеру, браузер может из миллионов строк кода состоять и
>   потребовать миллионов отдельных вопросов, которые можно на SO задать).

Если разбить задачу на, скажем, 5 вопросов, получить ответ на 4, то в решении конечной задачи мне это не особо поможет. Затык всегда будет в каком-то месте. Закон Парето.

Единственное, эти дополнительные вопросы наполнят нашу базу сообщества, что опосредованно поможет другим людям.

> В голове мнение засело [где-то после пары лет работы программистом
>   (давно)], что любую проблему можно разбить на [возможно длинную]
>   череду (лес) простых шагов

Ну да, если у человека есть экспертиза в этом деле. Если человек пришёл на SO задавать вопрос, то, вполне вероятно, у него оной нету. Если мне нужно на сервере организовать работу с БД и настроить всё это дело с хорошей отказоустойчивостью (а до этого я работал с базой только на сингл ноде и про репликацию с шардингом ничего не слышал), то вряд ли я смогу разбить вопрос.

Comment: не вижу примеров "недетских" вопросов

Comment: @jfs видишь суслика? Нет? А он есть (с)

Comment: чтобы не было непониманий, явно выделите в вашем сообщении пример (что вы считаете примером "трудной проблемы", ответ на которую "почти всегда" невозможно на Stack Overflow получить)¶ Для ясности: спрашивающий не обязан уметь разбивать на более простые вопросы, достаточно, чтобы человек, пишущий ответ мог это сделать (к примеру, [человек, задавший вопрос, может не знать слов "линейное программирование"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/825127/23044), это не значит, что ответ нельзя получить)

Comment: @jfs гипотетические? Или ссылки на конкретные вопросы на SO? Или ссылки на сложные задачи с других сайтов не в сети SO?

Comment: *"Интересуют реальные вопросы из практики, на которые есть ответ где-то (идеально со ссылкой)."*  Ссылки, где угодно (списки рассылок, bug trackers, чаты самые разные -- если логов нет, то достаточно своими словами пересказать).