# "Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса" vs "Stackoverflow — это база знаний"

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Сразу скажу, что если подобный вопрос уже обсуждали, не стесняйтесь ткнуть меня в него, поскольку на мете и в чате я редкий посетитель.

---

Собственно вопрос вот в чем. У нас есть такая причина закрытия как "необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса", предназначенная для того, чтобы закрывать вопросы в духе "Как мне сделать пепелац?". Мы хотим видеть от задающих вопросы с конкретными проблемами.

С другой стороны, мы говорим о том, что StackOverflow — это база знаний. И русский сайт предназначен в том числе для тех, кто в силу каких-то причин не дружит с английским. И вот тут мне видится некоторое противоречие: человек хочет что-то сделать, английского он не знает, в рунете информации нет (или ее очень сложно найти). Человек приходит к нам с этим вопросом, а вопрос закрывают. Однако вместо этого что мы могли бы стать местом, где следующий человек с таким же вопросом нашел бы ответ.

Например, вот [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478572/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82-share-%D0%B2-uwp) подпадает под закрытие:

> Как реализовать кнопку "Поделиться" в UWP проекте?

Мол, иди, милок, сначала почитай гугл, попробуй сделать сам, а если что-то будет не получаться, возвращайся и спрашивай. Вроде бы разумно. В англоязычном интернете информация находится очень быстро. Постарался я ее также найти в рунете. И не смог!

С одной стороны — идеальный кандидат на закрытие, с другой стороны — вопрос весьма точный, полезен для новичков; рунет на него не дает ответа, но ответ есть, причем весьма точный, и этот ответ мог бы увеличить ценность сайта как русскоязычной базы знаний. Так что же делать?

Comment: Вопрос по ссылке ещё не закрыт и даже не заминусован.

Comment: @D-side этот вопрос лишь конкретный пример.

Comment: Слабоват пример, на мой взгляд. "идеальный кандидат на закрытие", но при этом "ответ есть, причем весьма точный"?

Comment: @D-side: он уже не закрыт )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мета обычно тоже помогает)))

Answer (score 6):

1. [Закрытие вопросов по базовым действиям для чего-либо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/239/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE)
2. Пишешь комментарий, что хочешь ответить.
3. Голосуешь за переоткрытие.
4. Если не помогает: [Вероятно, некоторые вопросы заслуживают переоткрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1839/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)
5. При особом желании можно продублировать в общем чате.

Можно и без пункта 2, но тогда вероятность переоткрытия меньше.

Если вопрос ещё не закрыт, но ты хочешь на него ответить, то резервируешь ответ - пишешь какой-то текст в качестве ответа и сам этот ответ сразу удаляешь. Тогда независимо от закрытости вопроса (ну, если его не удалят), ты сможешь при помощи правки написать ответ, после чего его восстановить. Я в таких случаях ещё пишу комментарий автору - не уверен, сработает ли автоуведомление. Дальше по пунктам 3-5.

Обычно наличие ответа помогает. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470818/openoffice-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F).

PS: А вообще, я считаю, что такие вопросы закрывать надо далеко не всегда.

Answer (score 6):

"Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса" — это страшный гибрид нескольких причин закрытия, на него я бы особо не ориентировался. Изначально там была причина закрытия "unclear what you are asking", то есть причина закрытия использовалась для случаев, когда неясно, в чём именно состоит вопрос. Сейчас же это мутант MCVE и too broad.

Вот о последней причине закрытия "too broad" ("необходимо конкретизировать вопрос" в местной терминологии) и можно говорить как об основной проблеме с этим вопросом.

Посмотрите на этот вопрос:

> Как реализовать кнопку "Поделиться" в UWP проекте?

Задумайтесь, о чём нужно рассказать. Нужно рассказать, как добавлять кнопки в приложение, как рисовать на них иконки, какие есть шрифты, как размещать кнопки на тулбарах, как обрабатывать их нажатие... Правда это при условии, что имеется в виду Win10, а не Win8.1, тогда нужно будет рассказывать про обработку нажатия "Поделиться" в общем тулбарчике. И это мы ещё не дошли до собственно "деления", дальше у нас идёт обработка запроса на данные, задание свойств всяких... Расписав на несколько страниц огромный ответ, вы утираете пот с лица и говорите автору вопроса:

— Вот, смотри, какой я тебе шедевр написал!

И слышите в ответ:

— А что такое XAML?

— А какие ещё есть шрифты?

— А как расшарить картинку?

Что вы на это скажете?

Так что давайте стремиться к тому, чтобы вопросы не стимулировали написание многостраничных статей. Это не формат Stack Overflow. Тут конкретные проблемы — конкретные решения.

Comment: Почему же вы тогда сами запостили ответ на него? :) (Ровно тот, который я хотел дать.)

Comment: И все  это напрашивается один единственный ответ -- *не хочешь отвечать, пройди мимо*.